# Getting view with liquid buttons

Tags: ios, ios7, uiview, uibutton, uilabel

1. Consider that we have a formula: `buttona texta buttonb textb buttonc textc buttond text`. Fixed number of buttons (each of which has different length of course) and *possibly* dynamic number of text labels.
2. What is the most easiest way to get a `UIView` with liquid buttons as well as text labels based on that? Please, see an example.
3. Of course we can find a correlation with `html` displaying. Perhaps we have existing components to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve this using `NSAttributedString` class. Check [this link](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-use-nsattributedstring-in-ios-6.html) for examples.